# How to use setup menu(values) behavior of Semantic ui to populate a dropdown with values from database

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, jstl, semantic-ui

So I have a form created by using JSP and Servlet in that form i have a dropdown which i am trying to populate with the values which are in my database by using semantic UI behavior [enter link description here][1] (setup menu(values)).

Can someone please help regarding this ?? , Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

I'll add the code which i have tried below.

This is my Dropdown and i am using  element instead of .

```
            <div class="required field">
                <label> Main Category </label>
                    <select name = "home_main_category"  id = "home_main_cat_dropdown_id" >
                        <option value = "" > Category </option>
                    </select>
            </div>
```

this is how i am trying to use semantic behavior setup menu(values) but i am not sure what to give in place of name text and value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
            $("#home_main_cat_dropdown_id").dropdown('setup menu',{ values: [{ value: '${category.main_category}' , name: 'main_category' }] });     
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
         
         $("#home_main_cat_dropdown_id").dropdown('setup menu', { values: '${category.main_category}' } ); 

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        
         $("#home_main_cat_dropdown_id").dropdown('setup menu(values)', ['${category.main_category}'] );  
    
</script>
```

please can anyone give some sample code of how to implement this behavior ??

Comment: Did you try the various options on your own? What results (or errors) got?

Comment: @cheesyMan YES i tried them on my own. 
No,error as such but in dropdown it was showing main_category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

###### 1. Better go with Fomantic-UI

First of all, I **strongly** suggest you to switch to [`Fomantic-UI`](https://fomantic-ui.com/), that's a fork of `Semantic-UI`, but it's **actively mantained** and updated, while Semantic-UI is kind of abandoned (Semantic-UI last update was in 2018).

Fomantic-UI has the same components and functionalities of Semantic-UI, but Fomantic-UI added new and useful features/settings to several components/modules and also created brand new ones (like **[toasts](https://fomantic-ui.com/modules/toast.html)** or **[calendar](https://fomantic-ui.com/modules/calendar.html)**).

###### 2. Dropdown menu

That said, you can **setup**/**re-create** a dropdown's menu in this way:

```
$(dropdownElement)
   .dropdown('setup menu', { values: some_array });
```

where `some_array` is an array (*You don't say?!? :D* ) shaped like this:

```
some_array = [
   {value: '', name: '', text: ''},
   {value: '', name: '', text: ''},
   ...
   {value: '', name: '', text: ''},
]
```

- `value` is the value (for the given `<option>`) that will be stored in dropdown's hidden `<input>` field
- `name` is the text (of the given `<option>`) that is shown in the list of options when you open the dropdown.
- `text` is the text (of the given `<option>`) that will be shown in the dropdown when you select that option

Both `name` and `text` accept also HTML markup, as you can see in the snippet below.

```js
const menuItems = [{
    value: 'john',
    name: '<span class="name red">- John -</span>',
    text: 'John selected'
  },
  {
    value: 'mary',
    name: '- Mary -',
    text: 'Mary selected'
  },
  {
    value: 'james',
    name: '- James -',
    text: '<span class="text green">James!!!</span>'
  },
]

$("#home_main_cat_dropdown_id").dropdown('setup menu', {
  values: menuItems
});
```

```css
span.name.red {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #cecece;
}

span.text.green {
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.8.8/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.8.8/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="required field">
  <label> Main Category </label>
  <select name="home_main_category" id="home_main_cat_dropdown_id">
    <option value=""> Category </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much !! its a great explanation of how the behavior is actually working.
i'll try to implement like this and will let you know 
no matter if this works or not it cleared my doubts and i'll use fomantic now.
really appreciate the effort you have put in.